# Running cmd from powershell issue with escaping when running iisexpress

Tags: powershell, cmd, iis-express

I want to run iisexpress inside cmd and start it from powershell.
I have a strange issue with escaping double quotes.
My original powershell command is

```
Start-Process 'cmd' -ArgumentList '/k "C:/Program Files/IIS Express/iisexpress.exe" /config:"d:\Repo\app\applicationhost.config" /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool"'
```

It fails with

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

There is clearly some issues with double quotes, however when I try to run iis without arguments it actually starts it

```
Start-Process 'cmd' -ArgumentList '/k "C:/Program Files/IIS Express/iisexpress.exe"'
```

I noticed it feels fine until I type a double quote after `iisexpress.exe"`. For instance, just `Start-Process 'cmd' -ArgumentList '/k "C:/Program Files/IIS Express/iisexpress.exe" /config:"` is failing with `'C:/Program' is not recognized`, but `Start-Process 'cmd' -ArgumentList '/k "C:/Program Files/IIS Express/iisexpress.exe" /config:` also fails, but it tells that I should provide a value for the argument.

All in all, how to avoid the issue with arguments for iisexpress?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've run into a `cmd.exe` parsing "quirk", which you can avoid by enclosing everything that follows `/k` (or `/c`) in `"..."` (incredibly, this does then *not* require escaping the then *embedded* `"` chars):

```
Start-Process 'cmd' -ArgumentList '/k " "C:/Program Files/IIS Express/iisexpress.exe" /config:"d:\Repo\app\applicationhost.config" /apppool:"Clr4IntegratedAppPool" "'
```

The problem occurs when both a double-quoted executable path and double-quoted arguments are present and there is no overall `"..."` enclosure. (There are situational exceptions, but overall `"..."` enclosure is the safe choice.)